# beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications idiosyncrasy?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uidevice

Does `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`reset the status bar back to Portrait orientation?

In my app, logging o and p below:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation o = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
UIInterfaceOrientation p = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

I get:

```
o = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
p = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

Is it me, or is this expected behavior?  Where this bites me is that after I `beginGeneratingOrientationNotifications`, my notification routine gets called twice back to back, once for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and then `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` - which is the actual orientation of the iPhone at that moment.

Regardless of how the iPhone is held, I get one `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` notification before I get the correct one.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On iphone, the app is launched in the portrait mode and then rotated to the specified orientation.

Comment: I am not talking about launch time.  I am talking about anytime I start orientation notification with beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.  Regardless of how the device is held, it seems to generate a UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.  This happens hours after launch, and multiple orientation changes later.

Comment: so what is the problem then? the correct value gets updated in the next call.

Comment: Shall I always ignore the first call then?  The first call makes me rotate my UI into the wrong position.  The second call makes me rotate the UI into the correct position.  The user sees the UI rotate needlessly and then back.  Should I ignore that first call?  Am I guaranteed that the first call is always going to be incorrect and that a second one will correct it?

Comment: you can probably add the check when the new orientation is equal to the previous orientation, probably you can ignore such a situation. Also, where do you put beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications is also important. Where are you calling this from? inside you own method or after a callback.